# Implementing Print in TPS390 Android

Tags: java, android

I hello all, I know this old fashion, but I am very new to Android, and I am trying to implement Printing in a new TPS390 that I have got. I have added the Jar files to my App but in the below code when I click on the print method the app crashes and in the Logcat below is the error I am getting.

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                                    Process: com.example.userregister, PID: 3269
                                                                                                    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
                                                                                                        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:473)
                                                                                                        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
                                                                                                        at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1218)
                                                                                                        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
                                                                                                        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                                                    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                                                        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:468)
                                                                                                        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438) 
                                                                                                        at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1218) 
                                                                                                        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422) 
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733) 
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017) 
                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779) 
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595) 
                                                                                                        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
                                                                                                    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/telpo/tps550/api/printer/ThermalPrinter
                                                                                                        at com.example.userregister.HomeActivity.Print(HomeActivity.java:58)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                                                                        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:468) 
                                                                                                        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438) 
                                                                                                        at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1218) 
                                                                                                        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422) 
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733) 
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017) 
                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779) 
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595) 
                                                                                                        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

when I comment the try catch in the printing, I don't get any error so I sure know it is coming from the way I am trying to do the print. Thanks and I appreciate all your help
below is my code

enter code here

```
package com.example.userregister;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.telpo.tps550.api.printer.ThermalPrinter;

public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.home);

        String username = getIntent().getStringExtra("USERNAME");

        setName(username);
    }

    public String name;

    public void setName(String name){
        TextView mytext = findViewById(R.id.welcome_txt);
        mytext.setText("Welcome " + name);
    }

    public void logOut(View view){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    public void Print(View view){
        // Example printing logic using Telpo thermal printer SDK
        TextView errorMessage = findViewById(R.id.error_message_txt);
        try {
            ThermalPrinter.start(this);
            ThermalPrinter.reset();
            ThermalPrinter.setAlgin(ThermalPrinter.ALGIN_LEFT);
            ThermalPrinter.setLeftIndent(10); // Adjust left distance as needed
            ThermalPrinter.setLineSpace(20); // Adjust line distance as needed
            ThermalPrinter.setFontSize(3); // Example font size
            ThermalPrinter.setGray(12); // Example gray level
            ThermalPrinter.addString("Your content to print"); // Replace with your content
            ThermalPrinter.printString();
            ThermalPrinter.clearString();
            ThermalPrinter.walkPaper(100); // Walk paper as needed
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Print", "Exception occurred: " + e.getMessage());
            String error = String.valueOf(e);
            errorMessage.setText(error);
            // Handle exceptions if needed
        } finally {
            ThermalPrinter.stop(this);
        }
    }
}
```